# htaccess - include a file if query value is true

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to override my PHP script with htaccess

if my query string contain `http://loaclhost/index.php?feed=true` then I want to load `feed.php` file instead of default `index.php`

And I want to keep this htaccess file with above rule inside a sub directory.

Please help me.

Comment: Nice. But this is not twitter, and not a "code for free" service. Try something, then come back if stuck at an exact problem. Be sure to read the [FAQ].

Comment: Why do you need ` I want to keep this htaccess file with above rule inside a sub directory.` You need to understand that `.htaccess` is per directory thing and it only impacts URL going to that path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} feed=true
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ feed.php [L]
```

If you have to keep this rule in a subdirectory, then it will **only affect requests inside that subdirectory**. That means `http://loaclhost/index.php` won't even bother evaluating your htaccess file. But if you're trying to access the index.php in that subdirectory then the above should work, possibly require a `RewriteBase /subdirectory-name/` to include the name of your subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use simple PHP function with $_GET to include feed.php instead of index.php, in iframe. So you will have main file and depending on $_GET value different file will be loaded in iFrame.

Comment: actually I dont want to customize core script code, so I am trying to do it a htaccess rule

Comment: than looks like you are working on some open source engine. If this was a custom coding it will be easy to do above as you know your own code :) As well I do not agree with ppeterka 66, very cocky and not polite.